# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState while adding fragment via xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, illegalstateexception

I have an activity and in its xml file I am adding a fragment like below (not the exact code)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/webview_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In my java file I don't have any code relating to FragmentTransaction as I am adding my fragment in the xml file itself.
Observed below crash in monkey testing of the application. I have read most of the solutions regarding this issue and I know I need to check for isFinishing(). But since I am adding the fragment via xml would like to know how can I prevent it.

```
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1413)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:576)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2570)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at miui.app.Activity.onBackPressed(SourceFile:167)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2544)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2676)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2801)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4183)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4145)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3691)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3744)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3710)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3893)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3691)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3744)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3710)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3691)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3744)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3710)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3869)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4037)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2292)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1913)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1904)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2269)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:141)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
07-17 20:56:40.527  7032  7032 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Comment: The error is thrown by a particular code row? if yes, can you post it? if not, can you still post your fragment/activity back logics? the error is thrown in the fragment finish operation or in the activity one?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley sorry for the late reply. I am not able to identify which line of code is causing it. The activity has a fragment added via xml and the fragment contains a webview.